# Maximal value for total angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, representation-theory

Let us have a state $\left|\psi\right>$ that is an eigenstate of both $J^2,\,J_3$ with eigenvalues $l,\,m$ correspondingly. A common argument goes that $l^2-m^2\geq0$ since $J^2-J^2_3=J_1^2+J_2^2$, but I don't understand its meaning since we know nothing about $\left|\psi\right>$'s relation to $J_1,\,J_2$.

Comment: What do you get by sandwiching both sides of your equation with your psi as bread?

Comment: I'll get $l-m^2$ on one side, and on the other side $\left<J_1\psi|J_1\psi\right>+\left<J_2\psi|J_2\psi\right>$? which is positive

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the relationship between $l$ and $m$:

- There is an integer $j\ge 0$ such that $l = j(j+1)$, because of the way angular momentum works.
- The eigenvalue m must be between $+j$ and $-j$, because of the way angular momentum works.
- Find the smallest that $l-m^2$ can be. It's definitely positive.

Its meaning is that we don't know what $J_1|\psi >$ and $J_2|\psi >$ are.